# How to put "enter" or "return" when sending text in iTerm2

Tags: iterm2, iterm

[This is an image of where I want to put "enter" or "return" i.e. inside the "command"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xY1NB.png)

While I can put characters, I do not know how to "enter" so that it can run a line and another one inside command. I am having a same problem for "send text" -- I want to be able to send a text and have the shortcut run it by "enter"ing.

i would appreciate your help.

thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try adding `\n` after the command in "send text" e.g a key mapped to `code . \n` will open vscode in the current folder.